# Scrapy throws module initialization error: 'twisted.internet.reactor' when runnning on AWS Lambda

Tags: scrapy, twisted, aws-lambda

I m trying to run a scrapy spider in AWS Lambda.

I am getting this error :

```
module initialization error: 'twisted.internet.reactor'
```

how can I move forward ?

Edit :
I read [Scrapy throws error ReactorNotRestartable when runnning on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388541/scrapy-throws-error-reactornotrestartable-when-runnning-on-aws-lambda)
which relates to a different error. None of the answers seems to apply to my case.

Comment: Unmark the question. The situation is similar but the error is different. I have looked into the Crochet library you are supporting, I cannot use it.

Comment: For anyone interested, I finally found out that something wen't wrong during the installation of twisted (the environnement wasn't exactly identical to AWS lambda environnement). I solved the issue by having a lambda function run scrapy installation steps then zip and send me the dependencies folder (this way the dependencies are built by and for AWS lambda)