# module initialization error: 'twisted.internet.reactor' when running scrapy on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, twisted, aws-lambda

I m trying to run a scrapy spider in AWS Lambda.

I am getting this error :

```
module initialization error: 'twisted.internet.reactor'
```

The spider is running fine on an EC2 linux AMI

So far I have tried :

- using crochet to make scrapy behave like a blocking process.
  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crochet
- using [ScrapyScript](https://github.com/jschnurr/scrapyscript) to have twisted run outside of the main
  thread.
- re-installing twisted (pip install twisted)
- running scrapy with `stop_after_crawl=False` as it seemed to act as a
  workaround for the author of
  [Scrapy throws error ReactorNotRestartable when runnning on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388541/scrapy-throws-error-reactornotrestartable-when-runnning-on-aws-lambda)

Comment: Did it work in the end?

Comment: No I never made it work on AWS lambda. I fell back on using an EC2 server

Comment: Thanks Hugo! Saves time!