# While trying to test Scrapy Web-Crawler on AWS Lambda got this error "raise error.reactornotrestartable() "

Tags: python, aws-lambda, scrapy, web-crawler

I deployed my web-crawler to the AWS Lambda. Then While testing, it ran correctly for the first time, but the second time it gave this error.
raise error.reactornotrestartable() twisted.internet.error.reactornotrestartable in AWS lambda

```
File "/var/task/main.py", line 19, in run_spider
    reactor.run()
  File "/var/task/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1282, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "/var/task/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1262, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "/var/task/twisted/internet/base.py", line 765, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

The crawler worked fine on my local python environment. The function I am trying to run inside main.py is this

```
def run_spider(event, s):
    given_links = []
    print(given_links)
    for t in event["Records"]:
        given_links.append(t["body"])
    runner = CrawlerRunner(s)
    deferred = runner.crawl('spider', crawl_links=given_links)
    deferred.addCallback(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()

def lambda_handler(event, context=None):
    s = get_project_settings()
    s['FEED_FORMAT'] = 'csv'
    s['FEED_URI'] = '/tmp/output.csv'
    run_spider(event, s)
```

where the event looks like this:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "body": "https://example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Initially, I was using CrawlerProcess instead of CrawlerRunner, but it also gave the same error. Then after looking through some of the answers on StackOverflow, I changed my code to use CrawlerRunner. Some people also suggested using Crochet, I tried that and got this error:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread in scrapy
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: May this be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42388541/939364 ?

Comment: Maybe, you are right, but none of the solutions are working for me on that link. The sys.exit() answer is working finally but I wanted something less dirty. So, I thought it would be better to ask the question again? I am sorry if it's wrong, I am just new to this StackOverflow stuff.

Comment: I would personally just vote up the original question and share it in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/scrapy/), asking if anyone can think of a cleaner method.

Answer (score 1):

I faced error `ReactorNotRestartable` on AWS lambda and after I came to this solution

By default, the asynchronous nature of `scrapy` is not going to work well with Cloud Functions, as we'd need a way to block on the crawl to prevent the function from returning early and the instance being killed before the process terminates.

Instead, we can use `scrapydo` to run your existing spider in a blocking fashion:

```html
import scrapy
import scrapy.crawler as crawler
rom scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
import scrapydo

scrapydo.setup()

# your spider
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/tag/humor/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            print(quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first())

scrapydo.run_spider(QuotesSpider)
```